# Webscraping using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dropdown

I am very new to Python and I am trying to get all store locations from website of Muthoot. the following is a code i wrote but i am not getting any output. Please let me know what is wrong and what i need to correct.
As i understand, the code is not getting the search button clicked and hence nothing is moving. But how to do that??

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Chromedriverpath\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.muthootfinance.com/branch-locator")
#Saving this element in a variable
drp=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("statelist"))
slist=drp.options

for ele in slist:    
    table=driver.select("table.table")
    columns=table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    column_names=[c.string for c in columns]
    table_rows=table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    l=[]
    for tr in table_rows:
        td=tr.find_all('td')
        row=[str(tr.get_text()).strip() for tr in td]
        l.append(row)
    
df=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=column_names)  
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you now, I copied your code and it seems to work!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.muthootfinance.com/branch-locator")
# Saving this element in a variable

html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("state_branch_list")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    places = item.text
    print(places)


df = pd.DataFrame([places])
```